# SQL - Calculating percent of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table that looks like this:

```
id,field
40,Agree
41,Agree
42,Disagree
43,Strongly agree
45,Strongly agree
46,Agree
47,Neutral
48,Agree
```

I would like to output the perfect of response where the field is Agree or Strongly agree. In this case it would be 6/8 or 0.75.

I am not too sure how to approach it but my guess will be that I will need to use subquery to select a table containing only the two responses that I am interested in and then divide that by the row count of the original table.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: done, sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when field in ('Agree', 'Strongly Agree') then 1.0 else 0
           end) as ratio
from t;
```